# Пауза между вызовом onNext в RxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Вот код:

```
Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.range(1, 1000)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            subs = obs.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer number) {
                    mCurrentNumber = number;
                    mCounter.setText(String.valueOf(number));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    isRunning = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
```

Как сделать так, чтобы между вызовом метода onNext была указанная мною пауза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .take(1000)
         .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
          @Override public void call(Long timerValue) {

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.zip(
            Observable.range(1, 1000),
            Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            new Func2<Integer, Long, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call(Integer integer, Long aLong) {
                    return integer;
                }
            });
```